# How to reveal on scroll in Ionic v4?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, frontend

I'm trying to make a reveal on scroll with Ionic, until now I was using ngx-scrollreveal (https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-scrollreveal) which is working fine with my angular pages.

[image: https://content-static.upwork.com/blog/uploads/sites/3/2018/03/14081052/animation_scrollreveal.gif]

With the Ionic Grid system the reveal animations act weirdly, they are only trigger by changing the viewport size.

```
<div [ngsReveal]="{reset: true}" >Outside ion-content</div>
<ion-content padding>
    <div [ngsReveal]="{reset: true}" >Inside ion-content : Only display if the object is on view page load</div>
    <ion-grid fixed>
        <div [ngsReveal]="{reset: true}" >Inside ion-grid : Only display when page's size change</div>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Also the reset option seems to not be functional. (The object should fade away when is out of the viewport.)

I am using the wrong material for the effect I want? Or is it just a problem with my grid?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work smoothly using ng-in-viewport instead.

https://github.com/rivafarabi/ionic-scroll-reveal